# What network bandwidth should I expect on GCE?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to host a webradio station, using an icecast2 server, on a google compute engine instance in the europe-west1-a zone. This service is mainly bandwidth limited so I've searched the documentation to found an estimate of how much bandwidth is available (from my server to the internet) and I couldn't found it.

I've run som preliminary tests, by simulating listeners with curl processes on a single remote server with 100 Mbps of bandwith. My tests started failing at 500 listeners. The stream was encoded at 64kbps so the server was outputing ~32Mbps. From the way the test is run, I can't conclude the bandwidth is the limiting factor but still I'd like to know how much bandwidth I should expect to estimate the number of concurrent listeners I can have.

Answer (score 8):

100 Megabit/second is expected. Your test might not be accurate if you are testing from single host, how do you know that the bottleneck is not the receiving end.

Here is my test 1 vCPU, 3.8 GB memory GCE instance:

- install nginx
- download debian-update-7.1.0-amd64-CD-1.iso to the instance www root

use two remote servers in Asia as clients parallel with 5 threads each using axel
http://axel.alioth.debian.org/

- host 1: Downloaded 639.1 megabytes in 1:31 seconds. (7132.22 KB/s)
- host 2: Downloaded 639.1 megabytes in 1:41 seconds. (6452.50 KB/s)

total: 
13584.72 KB/s = 108.67 Mbits/s

Answer (score 6):

Test result from my 'g1-small' instance:

```
CPU model :  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2689 0 @ 2.60GHz
Number of cores : 1
CPU frequency :  2599.998 MHz
Total amount of ram : 1699 MB
Total amount of swap : 0 MB
I/O speed :  55.1 MB/s

Download speed from CacheFly, CDN: 16.5MB/s
Download speed from Linode, Tokyo, JP: 10.1MB/s
Download speed from Linode, London, UK: 14.7MB/s
Download speed from Linode, Newark, NJ: 27.5MB/s
Download speed from Linode, Atlanta, GA: 17.8MB/s
Download speed from Linode, Dallas, TX: 7.57MB/s
Download speed from Linode, Fremont, CA: 22.2MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, Dallas, TX: 52.6MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, Seattle, WA: 28.0MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, Washington, DC: 35.6MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, Houston, TX: 47.3MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, San Jose, CA: 26.6MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, Singapore, Singapore: 8.09MB/s
Download speed from SoftLayer, Amsterdam, NL: 14.9MB/s
```

Comment: Are those Megabit or MegaByte?